# Hover menu wont open, on hover

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

Im creating an app looking page.

I want one of my buttons on the menu in the bottom to open up, when i hover the mouse.

It feels like a simple task, but nothing i do seems to work.
What am i missing, ive done a lot of research but cant seem to find a solution.

I tried to to use display: none; to hide the popup list, and display: block; to show it.

in this version i'ved tried visibility: hidden; and visibility: visible; to show it.

I'm not sure where my problem lies, but it could be my hover selector is written wrong?

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #226949;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -8px;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar img {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #184e34;
  color: white;
}

.navbar img:hover {
  background: #184e34;
}

.All_Content {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 42px;
}

.settings_popup {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #226949;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 52px;
  height: 160px;
  width: 130px;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #184e34;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.settings_popup a {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-left: -37px;
  background-color: #226949;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.settings_popup a:hover {
  background: #184e34;
}

.navbar ul a:hover .settings_popup {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
  <title>App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="All_Content">
    <div>Overview</div>
    <p>asdasd1</p>
    <p>asdasd2</p>
    <p>asdasd3</p>
    <p>asdasd4</p>
    <p>asdasd5</p>
    <p>asdasd6</p>
    <p>asdasd7</p>
    <p>asdasd8</p>
    <p>asdasd9</p>
    <p>asdasd10</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="settings_popup">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="link" href="#">Account</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a class="link" href="#">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar">
      <a class="dash_a" href="#">Dashboard</a>
      <a href="#">Statistics</a>
      <a href="#">Logout</a>
      <div class="cogwh">
        <img src="../../img/4200781-32.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to have the menu pop up (class settings_popup) , but it does nothing.

Is there a way i can debug this?

Comment: do you have a live webpage where we can see?

Comment: when you want to show the setting_popup block?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Keeping your code as is, you can add the following JavaScript code to achieve your result

```js
var popup = document.querySelector('.settings_popup')
var trigger = document.querySelector('.navbar')
trigger.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    popup.style.visibility = 'visible'
})
trigger.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    popup.style.visibility = 'hidden'
})
```

```css
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #226949;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -8px;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar img {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    background: #184e34;
    color: white;
}

.navbar img:hover {
    background: #184e34;
}

.All_Content {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 42px;
}

.settings_popup {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #226949;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 52px;
    height: 160px;
    width: 130px;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #184e34;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}

.settings_popup a {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin-left: -37px;
    background-color: #226949;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.settings_popup a:hover {
    background: #184e34;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="All_Content">
            <div>Overview</div>
            <p>asdasd1</p>
            <p>asdasd2</p>
            <p>asdasd3</p>
            <p>asdasd4</p>
            <p>asdasd5</p>
            <p>asdasd6</p>
            <p>asdasd7</p>
            <p>asdasd8</p>
            <p>asdasd9</p>
            <p>asdasd10</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="settings_popup">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="link" href="#">Account</a></li>
                    <li><a class="link" href="#">Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a class="link" href="#">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar">
                <a class="dash_a" href="#">Dashboard</a>
                <a href="#">Statistics</a>
                <a href="#">Logout</a>
                <div class="cogwh">
                    <img src="../../img/4200781-32.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm somewhat new to the Javascript language and i hope you can explain whats going on in the addEventListener.

I get that we first say what we want to happen  with 'mouseover' and 'mouseleave'.

But after the comma, we put '() =>'  what does this mean?

Comment: The eventListener takes a function (in this case an anonymous arrow function), which then gets executed. The () => {} part can be rewritten as function () { }, it's just a shorthand. So whenever you hover the element (mouseenter), the arrow function gets executed and sets the `visibility` style to visible. When you leave the element (mouseleave), it gets set back to hidden. Hope that clears it up for you.

Comment: So with the current code, whenever i hover the mouse above 'navbar', the class settings_popup will appear. How can i expand this code to say, if the mouse leaves both our trigger(navbar) and the popup(settings_popup) is should close?

Right now, the popup will dissapear when i move my mouse to it.

Comment: Since it's hard to do this via comments, I will just give you a pseudo-solution, you should do your own research and experiment. Instead of directly hiding the element on `mouseleave` I would start a timer, let's say 1 seconds, after which I would hide the popup. Then add another two event listeners for the popup, again `mouseover` and `mouseleave`. On `mouseover` kill the aforementioned timer. On `mouseleave` hide the popup.

Answer (score 0):

```css
li{
list-style:none}
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #226949;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -8px;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar img {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar img:hover {
    background: #184e34;
}

.All_Content {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 42px;
}

.settings_popup {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #226949;
    position: inherit;
    bottom: 52px;
    height: 160px;
    width: 130px;
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #184e34;
    visibility:hidden;

}

.settings_popup a:hover {
    background: #184e34;
}
.navbar a:hover~.settings_popup{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="All_Content">
            <div>Overview</div>
            <p>asdasd1</p>
            <p>asdasd2</p>
            <p>asdasd3</p>
            <p>asdasd4</p>
            <p>asdasd5</p>
            <p>asdasd6</p>
            <p>asdasd7</p>
            <p>asdasd8</p>
            <p>asdasd9</p>
            <p>asdasd10</p>
        </div>
            
            <div class="navbar">
                <a class="dash_a" href="#">Dashboard</a>
                <a href="#">Statistics</a>
                
                <a href="#">Logout</a>
                
                <div class="cogwh">
                    <img src="../../img/4200781-32.png">
                </div>
                <div class="settings_popup">
                  <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
                      <li><a ref="#">Settings</a></li>
                      <li><a  href="#">Logout</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's new in this answer ? as compare to previous answers? looks like copy paste